# how to specific page use angular router

Tags: angular, routes

I wanna switch two page with angular router and I have added those two components to the angular router but, no matter what url I try, browser always show "login" component. If I remove "login", the "dashboard" show successfully.

This is my sample code:

dashboard.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent   {
  title = 'dashboard';
}
```

login.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  title = 'login';
}
```

---

app.component.html

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Here is AppComponent';
    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [DashboardComponent, LoginComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot( appRoutes,
    { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

---

index.html

```html
..
..
<base href="/">

</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess problem is component `selector: 'app-root'`?

I hope someone can help me and thanks for your help a lot.

Comment: change your login selector to `app-login` and dashboard selector to `app-dashboard` selector must be unique for each component

Comment: ok, i found the error, first one, selector property from the @Component decorator

Comment: and remove  @NgModule  bootstrap: [DashboardComponent, LoginComponent]  at app.module.ts, it should be  [AppComponent] only

Answer (score 1):

The selectors of both your components are same. i.e app-root.

Remove the selector property from the @Component decorator in both dashboard.component.ts and login.component.ts

Since you defined routes for these components in app.routing.module.ts, No need to declare selector property